# XSLT 2.0 validation fails with net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have below sample to validate xslt style sheet. In various forums it was mentioned that we should "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl" for xslt 2.0 style sheet. According I have updated my code. But this piece of code is working for only few cases. For example, the code does not work for the sample I have attached below. If I change sample style sheet version to 1 (version="1.0"), then code works fine. Otherwise it fails. I believe the sample style sheet is valid xslt 2.0 document.

This is causing lot of problem, how do I validate a style sheet before I parse?

```
   package com.ibm.mq.id;

   import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
   import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

   import net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl;

   public class xsltTransformationEx {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


        String path="C://Work//ex.xsl";
        TransformerFactoryImpl factory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
        try
        {

            javax.xml.transform.Templates template = factory.newTemplates(new  StreamSource(path));
            //VALIDATING  XSLT is valid or not
            //Transformer trans =  factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(path));

         template.newTransformer();
        }
        catch(TransformerConfigurationException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

And my Sample XSLT is below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:variable name="FamilyMembers"        select="bpws:getVariableData('HSPACT_FamlyNumbers')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="Molers_Output">
        <xsl:element name="Molers_Output">
             <!--
             <xsl:element name="row">
                       <xsl:value-of select="row"/>
            </xsl:element>
             -->
            <xsl:for-each select="row[Hosp_Acct_Num = $FamilyMembers/rows/row/normalize-   space(HACCT_)]">
                <xsl:variable name="Account"><xsl:value-of select="Hosp_Acct_Num"></xsl:value-of></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="row">
                    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="name()='Family_Num'">
                                <xsl:element name="Family_Num">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$FamilyMembers/rows/row[normalize-space(HACCT_) = $Account]/HAFAM_"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="yes" inherit-namespaces="yes">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                                </xsl:copy>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>        
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: and what do you mean by fail ?

Comment: Hi Jean Fail in the sence .. When I ran this program in eclipse I am getting this error

Comment: Error at xsl:variable on line 6 column 93 of ex.xsl: XPST0017: XPath syntax error at char 43 on line 6 in {...bleData('HSPACT_FamlyNumber...}:
    Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named
  {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/}getVariableData()
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
 at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.prepare(PreparedStylesheet.java:176)
 atnet.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:139) at com.ibm.mq.id.xsltTransformationEx.main(xsltTransformationEx.ja

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard I have just updated the original problem summary with more details

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet has a call to a function named `bpws:getVariableData` in the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/` but there is no definition for that function so that you get a compilation error. You would need to define that function using `xsl:function` or `xsl:import/include` a module that defines the function.